# Why can't gauge bosons have mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, research-level, gauge-invariance

Clearly, a mass term for a vector field would render the Lagrangian not gauge-invariant, but what are the consequences of this? Gauge invariance is supposed to be crucial for the renormalisation of a vector field theory, though I have to say I'm not entirely sure why.

As far as removing unphysical degrees of freedom - why isn't the time-like mode $A_0$ a problem for massive vector bosons (and how does gauge invariance of the Lagrangian ensure that this mode is unphysical for gauge bosons)?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4700/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30546/

Answer (score 6):

Let me anwser a closely related quenstion:
*Consider a U(1) gauge theory with massless gauge bosons, can any small perturbations give the gauge boson an mass.*

Amazingly, the anser is NO. The masslessness of the gauge boson is topologically robust.
No small perturbations can give the gauge boson an mass.
For detail, see my [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0503554).

Let me make the statement more precise. Here we consider
a compact U(1) gauge theory with a finite UV cutoff (such as a lattice gauge theory),
that contains gapless gauge bosons at low energies.
Then no small perturbations to this compact U(1) gauge theory with a finite UV cutoff 
can give the gauge boson an mass, even for the small perturbations that break the gauge invariance.

So the masslessness of gauge boson is a stable universal property of a quantum phase.
Only a phase transition can make the gauge boson massive.

Comment: How to explain adding CS term in $1+2$d, or adding $A^\mu A_\mu$ term in $1+3$d?

Comment: For a well defined compact lattice gauge theory, adding a small mass term $A^\mu A_\mu$ does not affect the low energy property of the theory, ie does not give the gauge boson a mass. CS is quantized. One cannot add a small CS term.

Comment: Analogously, a photon (gauge particle) never has mass?

Answer (score 5):

Sure gauge bosons can have mass. The Higgs mechanism for one. Or in 2+1D, add a Chern-Simons term. Or in 3+1D, and a two-form gauge field B with the gauge symmetry $B \rightarrow B +d\lambda$ with $\lambda$ being any 1-form, and add a $B \wedge F$ coupling term.

If you mean why they can't have mass in the Coulomb gauge, the answer is topological. Look at the dispersion relation with helicities. A mass gap translates into an energy gap which would split the light cone dispersion into hyperboloids. Not possible topologically.

Answer (score 2):

As far as renormalizability of gauge bosons, a nonabelian gauge theory with massive gauge bosons is non-renormalizable as I describe here: [What evidence is there for the electroweak higgs mechanism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30546/what-evidence-is-there-for-the-electroweak-higgs-mechanism/30549#30549) . A massive abelian gauge boson is renormalizable and to my knowledge suffers no such defects at high energy as the would-be goldstone boson is from a linear sigma model, not a non-linear sigma model.

As far as the unphysical time-like modes, while there is no gauge invariance, what really matters is that its coupled to a conserved current, so there is still the cancelation that happens with massless gauge bosons.