# How do we know for sure a theory is non-renormalizable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In quantum field theory, we are looking for a Lagrangian that is, amongst other, renormalizable. But how do we determine whether or not a theory is renormalizable? Is this purely done by power counting due to Weinberg? **This question is already answered in a [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88884/semantic-problem-about-renormalizability).**

My question result from the fact that the Yang-Mills Lagrangian was considered to be non-renormalizable, and thus non-physical, for a decade until Veltman and 't Hooft found a method to regularize the theory. Keeping this in mind, **is it possible that there are theories that we today consider to be non-renormalizable, and thus non-physical, which actually *are* renormalizable but we haven't (yet) discovered a way to do this?**

I apologize in advance if my question is vague and if I'm using the wrong terminology, but I'm very new to the idea of renormalizability.

Comment: related post http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88884/ ; P.S. non-renormalizable Lagrangians are acceptable as effective theories

Comment: @user26143 thanks for that! I will now update my question (I don't think it answers my second question).

Comment: If a theory is power counting non-renormalizable, then for sure it is not renormalizable.

Comment: @JiaYiyang The point of this question seems to be: *Why* do you say that? Is there a good justification?

Comment: I answered this at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/13666

Comment: @JiaYiyang: this is only true at a perturbative level.

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/381544/7924

Comment: I think Yang-Mills was different from what you suggest. Power counting tells you the theory is conformal (classically). People just didn’t know how to renormalize them.

Comment: This isn't an answerable question in my opinion.