# What do the tensors here equal to?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

In the process $$e^+e^- \rightarrow \gamma \gamma$$ for which the amplitude can be written as: $M= \epsilon^*_{1\nu}\epsilon^*_{2\mu}(A^{\mu\nu}+\tilde{A}^{\mu\nu})$, where $\epsilon_i$ is the polarization vector of a photon. What do the tensors $A^{\mu\nu}$ & $\tilde{A}^{\mu\nu}$ equal to?[image]

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169126/2451

Comment: Photon propagators or amplitudes? They said they were tensors. @ACuriousMind

Comment: But again the line in the middle is a straight line and not a curved one to say it is a photon propagator.