# Does dimension of irreducible representations of the double cover $SU(2)$ of the 3D rotation group define spin of particle?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

In quantum field theory, does dimension of irreducible representations of  the double cover $SU(2)$ of the 3D rotation group conclusively define spin? In other words, Is spin 1 particle only thing that vector field in 4D spacetime can generate? Does spinor field always generate spin 1/2 particle?

Comment: related: [Can Poincare representations be embedded in non-standard Lorentz representations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383106/84967), [What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/84967), [Is Angular Momentum truly fundamental?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/822/84967) and links there in. (See also [In a universe with four spatial dimensions would there be elementary particles with intrinsic isoclinic spin?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221881/84967) for a more formal approach).

Answer (score 4):

1. In relativistic theories, an irreducible representation with spins $(j_L,j_R)\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0\times\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0$ for the [double cover $\tilde{G}_1=SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the] complexified proper [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $G_1=SO(1,3;\mathbb{C})$ decomposes into a direct sum $$(j_L,j_R)~=~\bigoplus_{j=|j_L-j_R|}^{j_L+j_R} j$$ of irreducible representations with spins $j\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0$ for the [double cover $\tilde{G}_2=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the] restricted Lorentz group $G_2=SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$.
2. In turn, an irreducible representation with spin $j\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0$ for the [double cover $\tilde{G}_2=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the] restricted Lorentz group $G_2=SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ is also an irreducible representation with the same spin $j\in\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0$ for the [double cover $\tilde{G}_3=SU(2)$ of the] 3D rotation group $G_3=SO(3,\mathbb{R})$.
3. *Examples.* A Lorentz vector is a $(1/2,1/2)$ representation. Left & right Weyl spinors are $(1/2,0)$ & $(0,1/2)$ representations, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) related Phys.SE post.
4. The particles corresponding to a field are usually classified in terms of the little group, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221881/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100995/2451) related Phys.SE posts and links therein.