# Why do we use the $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ rep for spin $1$ particles and not $(0, 1)$?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry

The spin 1 $A^\mu$ field transforms under the $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ representation of the Lorentz field. When restricted to the $SO(3)$ subgroup, it decomposes into the $0 \oplus 1$ representation of $SO(3)$. However, when using the massive Proca action, the spin $0$ degree of freedom is "killed off" by the equations of motion. (If the particle is massless, an extra degree of freedom is killed off, let's ignore that.)

What then was the point of using the $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}, \tfrac{1}{2}\right)$ representation to begin with? Why didn't we just use the $(1, 0)$ representation from the beginning?

Similarly, when we want to describe a spin 2 particle, we use the $(1, 1)$ representation and kill off degrees of freedom in the Lagrangian just like we did we the Proca action. What's the point? Why not just start with the $(0, 2)$ representation from the get-go?

To elaborate, there is a difference between the representations of the fields and the representations of the particles. However, which particle representations are actually present and "physical" are determined by the Lagrangian. The massive Proca Lagrangian kills of the spin $0$ particle. Is there some general way to construct Lagrangians that only give you the particles you want? And what's the point of keeping these un-physical representations around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Poincare representations be embedded in non-standard Lorentz representations?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383106/)

Comment: It's not the same representation. $(0,1)$ is not parity invariant.

Comment: The $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$ and  $(0, \frac{1}{2})$ reps are also not parity invariant. However, both can be used to write out the Lagrangian for a massive Majorana particle, which is parity invariant. So the way that parity interacts with the field rep isn't necessarily the same as the way it interacts with particles.